# Spring Boot REST endpoints not working , if add own dependencies in maven file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, web-services

I developed spring boot application (name as App1) with that app i'm connecting to the MQs( messaging queues ex: IBM MQ), App1 maven dependencies i'm added to the App2 and calling the App1 methods for connecting to the MQ's, but here i'm facing problem whenever add App1 dependencies into App2 then **App2 REST endpoints are not working(giving 404 response)**, could you please help me what might be the problem

**Note: if i remove the App1 dependencies in App2 then ,here REST controllers are working**

**App2 REST Controller Code:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/accept")
public class RequestController {

    @Autowired
    private Connector connector;
    
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendRequestTransactionEvent(@RequestBody TEvent tEvent) {

        //System.out.println("Received tEvent) request: " + tEvent) 
        System.out.println("rquest came to the controller");
        
        connector.sendRequestTransactionEvent(tEvent);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("message successfully sent ", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**App1 pom.xml file:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**App2 pom.xml file**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.app1</groupId>
            <artifactId>Env4x1-Mqjms</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```